# Apply a function twice compilation error Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I try to apply the function `edits1` twice, but I get a parse error on input "=" in the definition of `f`

```
delete1 :: String -> [String]
delete1 [] = []
delete1 (x:xs) = xs : map (x:) (delete1 xs)

replaced12 :: String -> [String]
replaced12 [] = []
replaced12 (x:xs) = [h c | c <- ['a'..'z']] ++ map (x:) (replaced12 xs)
         where h :: Char -> String
               h c = c:xs
replaced1 :: String -> [String]
replaced1 a = delete a $ replaced12 a

inserted1 :: String -> [String]
inserted1 [] = [] 
inserted1 (x:xs) = [ x:c:xs | c <- ['a'..'z']] ++ map (x:) (inserted1 xs)

transposed1 :: String -> [String]
transposed1 (x:y:xs) = (y:x:xs) : map (x:) (transposed1 (y:xs))
transposed1      xs  = []

edits1 :: String -> [String]
edits1 a = nub $ (delete1 a ++ replaced1 a ++ inserted1 a ++ transposed1 a)


edits2 :: String -> [String]
edits2 a = nub . f . edits1 a
         where f :: [String] -> [String]
               f []     = []
               f (x:xs) = (edits1 x) ++ map (x:) (f xs)
```

The first function is working, so the mistake must be in the 2'nd function but I can not figure out which is it. How can  I fix it ?

Comment: There aren't any syntax error in your code as posted. Make sure that you're not indenting code with a mix of tabs and spaces.

Comment: Could you please give more information like the exact error message or the missing function definition (delete1, replaced1 etc.) ? Without them, it’s more of a guess to try to help you

Comment: I just added the other functions

Comment: I have the following error, which is not a parsing error but a type error:

    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: Char
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘x’
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(x :)’

Comment: ok, but why is expecting Char? String should be fine. I don't know how I cand get over this.

Comment: The use of `map` in `transposed1` will expect `[Char]` since that function's argument has type `String`.

Comment: ok, I misstyped the code, instead of (edits2 xs) it is (f xs). And then I get parse error on input "= "

Comment: Can you update your original post with a copy paste of the full code ? Replacing `edits2 xs` by `f xs` still gives me a type error but no parse error

Comment: Can you also verify that there is no incorrect use of tabs vs space characters in your code ? (Try to change the tabs width in your editor’s settings with something like 10 characters to see if the indentation does change)

Comment: i copy/pasted the code

Comment: ok, there were some tabs, I don't have parse error anymore, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, but this time, we all talk about the same thing ;-)

Comment: ok, now why is : still expecting a Char, since f is returning a [String], shouldn't it expect a String?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should replace:

```
edits2 a = nub . f . edits1 a
```

with:

```
edits2 a = nub $ f (edits1 a)
```

Second, you have a problem with `f (x:xs) = (edits1 x) ++ map (x:) (f xs)`:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
Expected type: Char
  Actual type: String
In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘x’
In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(x :)’
```

From your definition, `x` is of type `String` and `xs` is of type `[String]`

`(x:)` is a function that takes a `[String]` as argument but `map` will try to apply it to each element of a `[String]` which are `String`. This cannot work.

**Edit after comments:**

The `edits2` function

```
edits2 :: String -> [String]
edits2 a = nub . f . edits1 a
         where f :: [String] -> [String]
               f []     = []
               f (x:xs) = (edits1 x) ++ map (x:) (f xs)
```

should be replaced with this version:

```
edits2 :: String -> [String]
edits2 a = nub $ foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ edits1 x) [] (edits1 a)
```

The first call to `edits1 a` apply the function to the argument. It then uses a fold to call `edits1` a second time and concatenate the results.

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to do. I admit I did only a typechecking, I did not try to really understand your code. Maybe are using `(:)` instead of `(++)`

Comment: If you replace `(x:)` with `(x++)` it compiles with no error, but I’m not sure it will do what you’re waiting for

Comment: What should do`edits2` ? (you can also give examples)

Comment: it should apply edits1 twice. first on the given string, it results a list and then on every element in that list and it results a bigger list. like: edits1 "ca" = [c, a, aca, bca ,....] and edits2 should apply edits1 on each element from that list, resulting a new list

Comment: Is this what you’re looking for ? `edits2 a = nub $ foldl (\a x -> a ++ edits1 x) (edits1 a) []`

Comment: I solved it. Your answer was almost good, but the order should be [] (edits1 a ) in the end. Thank you